# how to efficiently build up complex case class in my app flow?

Tags: scala, case-class

I have a controller method that extract the request from the client to `ModelOne`, and I need to change this model one and build it up to a bigger model lets call it `ModelTwo` so I can sent it to another service.

This is `ModelOne` case class:

```
case class ModelOne(list: List[String], expectedListSize: Int)
```

And this is `ModelTwo` case class:

```
case class ModelTwo(modelThree: Option[ModelThree])

case class ModelThree(status: Status(its enum),
                                        list: List[String],
                                        amount: Option[Int],
                                        message: Option[String])
```

So what I'm doing to build it up currently is whenever I get the request from the client in the controller I call a service that have a method to build it up since I need to take the `list` property from ModelOne and build ModelTwo, it looks like this:

```
def buildModelTwoResponse(modelOne: ModelOne): ModelTwo = {
    ModelTwo(Some(ModelThree(Status.Done, modelOne.list, None, None)))
}
```

so in the controller I go:

```
val modelOne = request.body.extractOpt[ModelOne]

val modelTwo = myService.buildModelTwoResponse(modelOne)
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more elegant way would be to define a second constructor for your `ModelTwo` type in its companion object by defining an `apply` function:

```
case class ModelTwo(modelThree: Option[ModelThree])

// Add this
object ModelTwo {

  // Move your service function logic to here
  def apply(modelOne: ModelOne): ModelTwo = {
    ModelTwo(Some(ModelThree(Status.Done, modelOne.list, None, None)))
  }
}
```

Then you wouldn't need your service function anymore, so instead of doing this:

```
// You don't need this
val modelTwo = myService.buildModelTwoResponse(modelOne)
```

You could do this:

```
val modelTwo = ModelTwo(modelOne)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
case class ModelOne(list: List[String], expectedListSize: Int) {
object ModelOne {
    buildResponse(modelOne: ModelOne): ModelTwo {
       ModelTwo.fromModelOne(modelOne)
    }
}

case class ModelTwo(modelThree: Option[ModelThree])
object ModelTwo {
     def fromModelOne(modelOne: ModelOne): ModelTwo = {
         fromModelThree(ModelThree.fromModelOne(modelOne))
     }

     def fromModelThree(modelThree: ModelThree): ModelTwo = {
         ModelTwo(Some(modelThree))
     }
 }

case class ModelThree(status: Status(its enum),
                                    list: List[String],
                                    amount: Option[Int],
                                    message: Option[String]) 
object ModelThree { 
   def fromModelOne(status: Status, modelOne: ModelOne): ModelThree = {
       ModelThree(status, modelOne.list, None, None)
   }
}
```